# How to turn an integer into vector and then turn that vector into string in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, integer, c++17

I want to take an integer and turn it into an array and then store it into a string in C++. But I do not know how to turn an integer into an array and then store it into a string. I am still learning C++, so help me, please. That's how I want it to be done:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int number = 3215;

  //store the number into vector
  vector<int> numbers;
  //vector[0]=3
  //vector[1]=2
  //vector[2]=1
  //vector[5]=5

  //and then store it into string
  string str;
  //like this
  //str=3215

  return 0;
}
```

**Please help me and show the code as well with explanation**

**Edit: I have some data to work with integer values with every digit which I can solve my own but for that, I need to first turn the integer into vector and return it as a string. THat's why I want to know how to turn integer into vector first and the that vector into string**

Comment: You can skip the vector thing and directly convert it to a `std::string` or a `char` array. Why do you need the vector?

Comment: You can use ```std::to_string```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> split(static_cast<int>(std::log10(n)) + 1);
    auto royal_10 = split.rbegin();
    auto cpy{ n };
    do {
        *royal_10++ = cpy % 10;
    } while ((cpy /= 10) != 0);
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(split.size());
    std::transform(split.cbegin(), split.cend(), std::back_inserter(ret),
        [](int const dig) { return dig + '0'; });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is : `std::to_string(yourNum);`

If you do need the steps:

```
std::vector<int> res;

int num;
std::cin >> num;

while(num>0)
    {
    res.insert(res.begin(),num%10);
    num/=10;
    }
```

and then

```
std::stringstream result;
std::copy(res.begin(), res.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(result, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you insist on placing the integers in a vector first and then converting them to string later (when needed?), this can be a solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main( )
{
    std::string number;
    std::cin >> number;

    std::vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve( number.length( ) );

    for ( const auto digit : number )
    {
        numbers.push_back( digit - '0' );
    }

    std::cout << "\nElements of vector: ";

    for ( const auto digit : numbers )
    {
        std::cout << digit << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << "\nElements of vector converted to `std::string`: ";

    for ( const auto num : numbers )
    {   
        std::string num_str { std::to_string( num ) };
        std::cout << num_str << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Sample I/O:**

```
1234

Elements of vector: 1 2 3 4
Elements of vector converted to `std::string`: 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a set of conversion functions, probably something like the [code below](https://ideone.com/ZADHvv). The ASCII codes of the digits are in **sequential order**, therefore transforming a digit character to a digit means subtracting `'0'` from it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

std::vector<int> convert(const std::string& s)
{
  std::vector<int> r;
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(r), [](auto e) {return e - '0'; });
  return r;
}

std::string convert(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
  std::string r;
  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(r), [](auto e) {return e + '0'; });
  return r;
}

std::vector<int> convert(const int n)
{
  return convert(std::to_string(n));
}

int main()
{
  auto v = convert(3215);
  auto s = convert(v);
  assert(s == "3215");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1)vector in c++ has vector object.push_back(); // which push data(any type) to vector array
2) using an iterator function you can retrieve that data and by dereferencing(*i)
you can receive that data in original form (which you had pushed)
3) use stringstream class or to_string() method to convert into string

//code
`

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
 int number=1234;
 string str;
 vector <int> obj;
 obj.push_back(number);
 for(auto i= obj.begin(); i!= obj.end();i++)
 {
  str = to_string((*i));
  cout << end << str;
 }
}
```

`

Comment: make at least sure your code compiles. I also am pretty sure it does not answers the questions of OP

Comment: buddy i am c++ developer for a long time I have tried this and it works and question is asked in wrong way i don't know what he want to exactly do